# can't set value for variable p in gdb

Tags: unix, gdb

In the application, variable with name `p` is used. I was trying to change value to check the behavior. However gdb is interpreting it incorrectly.

```
(gdb) set p=0
Undefined set print command: "=0".  Try "help set print".
(gdb) set p=0x0
Undefined set print command: "=0x0".  Try "help set print".

below line works fine.
(gdb) set size=900
```

i know changing variable name will work but then that will require stopping gdb and recompiling.

Answer (score 1):

> `(gdb) set p=0`

Try this instead:

```
(gdb) set var p = 0
```